# Stacked doing push notifications with AWS cognito, SNS and GCM

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging

If I register manually the token the app gives me in AWS SNS I can send push notifications, so I have almost done. I also get the connection with AWS Cognito. The AWS Cognito identity pool has the right role with AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonSNSFullAccess policy. This is my RegistrationIntentService.java:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.taboa.test2;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreatePlatformEndpointRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreatePlatformEndpointResult;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;


public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService{

    private static final String ROLE_ARN = "ROLE_ARN";
    private static final String AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = "000000000";
    private static final String IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "IDENTITY_POOL_ID";
    private static final Regions REGION = Regions.EU_WEST_1;

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};
    private static String token;

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
            // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);


            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer();

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            //subscribeTopics();

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * This method give us a call so as to get the tokenID of the phone's app
     */
    protected static String getToken(){
        return token;
    }


    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     */

    private void sendRegistrationToServer() {
        // initialize a credentials provider object with your Activity’s context
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // get the context for the current activity
                //AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
                IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // your identity pool id
                //ROLE_ARN,
                //null,
                REGION //Region
        );

        String customPushData = "It's in DB";//Custom id of the registered person


        AmazonSNSClient clientSNS = new AmazonSNSClient(credentialsProvider);

        //pushClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(REGION));
        CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = clientSNS.createPlatformEndpoint(
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                        .withCustomUserData(customPushData)
                        .withPlatformApplicationArn(ROLE_ARN)
                        .withToken(token)
        );

        result.getEndpointArn();



    }


    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics() throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }

}
```

I can run app without permison or graddle errors but it does not register automatically the token on amazon SNS. Probably the code in sendRegistrationToServer() is not well.

(EDIT)

Finally I've got it using AWS code because I had to use the ARN that amazon gives me to create a new one:

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer() {
        // initialize a credentials provider object with your Activity’s context
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // get the context for the current activity
                IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // your identity pool id
                REGION //Region
        );

        client= new AmazonSNSClient(credentialsProvider);

        client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(REGION));//VERY VERY IMPORTANT

        String customPushData = "It's in DB";//Custom id of the registered person

        CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq =
                new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                        .withCustomUserData(customPushData)
                        .withPlatformApplicationArn(ROLE_ARN)
                        .withToken(token);

        CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client
                .createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
        client.createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq).withEndpointArn(cpeRes.getEndpointArn());


    }
```

Comment: Would you please share AndroidManifest.xml? I am curious when RegistrationIntentService will be fired.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a [mcve].

Comment: @Yangfan sorry for not respondin before but is the same as here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest